# In bash print to line above terminal output

Tags: bash, terminal

**EDIT**: Corrected process/thread terminology

My shell script has a foreground process that reads user input and a background process that prints messages. I would like to print these messages on the line above the input prompt rather than interrupting the input. Here's a canned example:

```
sleep 5 && echo -e "\nINFO: Helpful Status Update!" &
echo -n "> "
read input
```

When I execute it and type "input" a bunch of times, I get something like this:

```
> input input input inp
INFO: Helpful Status Update!
ut input
```

But I would like to see something like this:

```
INFO: Helpful Status Update!
> input input input input input
```

The solution need not be portable (I'm using bash on linux), though I would like to avoid ncurses if possible.

**EDIT:** According to @Nick, previous lines are inaccessible for historical reasons. However, my situation only requires modifying the current line. Here's a proof of concept:

```
# Make named pipe
mkfifo pipe
# Spawn background process
while true; do
        sleep 2
        echo -en "\033[1K\rINFO: Helpful Status Update!\n> `cat pipe`"
done &
# Start foreground user input
echo -n "> "
pid=-1
collected=""
IFS=""
while true; do
        read -n 1 c
        collected="$collected$c"
        # Named pipes block writes, so must do background process
        echo -n "$collected" >> pipe &
        # Kill last loop's (potentially) still-blocking pipe write
        if kill -0 $pid &> /dev/null; then
                kill $pid &> /dev/null
        fi
        pid=$!
done
```

This produces *mostly* the correct behavior, but lacks CLI niceties like backspace and arrow navigation. These could be hacked in, but I'm still having trouble believing that a standard approach hasn't already been developed.

Comment: Those are "processes", not "threads".

Comment: I don't think there is a way to avoid curses here. Why do you want to avoid using the *de facto* standard facility for cursor addressing, and what (portable!) mechanism were you hoping would replace it?

Comment: Multithreaded applies to threads in a single process.  A shell script is not multithreaded.  Shells deal in multiple processes, not threads.

Comment: I wanted to avoid curses because it *seems* like this should be trivial. I do not need to edit previous lines, just the current one. For example, if I wanted to work super hard, I could read the input character by character, then when the status update occurs I overwrite the entire line and print the already-entered text on a new line. But this seems like it should already be a thing.

Answer (score 2):

The original ANSI codes still work in bash terminal on Linux (and MacOS), so you can use \033[F where \033 is the ESCape character. You can generate this in bash terminal by control-V followed by the ESCape character. You should see `^[` appear. Then type `[F`. If you test the following script:

```
echo "original line 1"
echo "^[[Fupdated line 1"
echo "line 2"
echo "line 3"
```

You should see output:

```
updated line 1
line 2
line 3
```

EDIT:

I forgot to add that using this in your script will cause the cursor to return to the beginning of the line, so further input will overwrite what you have typed already. You could use control-R on the keyboard to cause bash to re-type the current line and return the cursor to the end of the line.

Comment: This is a very promising approach, I wasn't aware of that escape sequence. Is there a way to bump down the current line while doing it? That way, if I printed multiple lines worth of status updates, the prompt would continue being pushed down the screen. Also, does the control-R have a cooresponding escape sequence so that it can be automated?

Comment: This question has taken me down memory lane! Bumping down: I don't think there is (remember these codes started in the days of paper terminals, so you couldn't do this physically!). Control-R is keyboard-only. There are two codes that 'should' do what you want in terms of returning the cursor to the end of the input line: SCP and RCP (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code). I was just trying them when you messaged, but they seem to be disabled/inactive.